Affine Transformation for "Securly" Comparing Integers
I just got into homomorphic encryption and multiparty computation. I thought about the following protocol for number comparison.
We use a treshold homomorphic encryption scheme (like the treshold version of the Damgard Jurik scheme). Let $n$ be the modulus of our encryption scheme. The scheme should support addition of ciphertexts and multiplication of cipher and plaintexts. Let $P_a$ and $P_b$ be two parties. Both have a private key share, and we have a treshold of 2, meaning, no party can decrypt a ciphertext on its own.
$P_a$ has an integer $m_a\in\{1,\dots,M\}$ and $P_b$ has an integer $m_b\in\{1,\dots,M\}$, with $m_a\neq m_b$ and $M<n$.
We choose two parameters $p_*,p_+\in\mathbb N$ with $p_+<p_*$, such that $(M\cdot p_*+p_+)< \frac n2$.
We define the function $T(a,x,y)=a\cdot x+y\ \text{mod}\ n$.
The protocol works as follows: $P_a$ sends $E(m_a)$ to $P_b$. $P_b$ generates two random values $x\in\{p_++1,\dots,p_*\}$ and $y\in\{-p_+,\dots,p_+\}$. And calculates $E(T(m_a-m_b,x,y))=(E(m_a)-E(m_b))\cdot x+E(y)$. $P_b$ now decrypts $E(T(m_a-m_b,x,y))$ with its private key share and sends it to $P_a$ (we have a treshold of 2, therefore $P_b$ can not fully decrypt the ciphertext). $P_a$ now decrypts the encrypted result, which yields $T(m_a-m_b,x,y)$. We have $T(m_a-m_b,x,y)<n/2$ iff $m_a-m_b>0$ iff $m_a>m_b$.
This protocol is of course not fully secure. For instance if $T(m_a-m_b,x,y)=1$, $P_a$ knows that $m_a-m_b=1$ and knows $m_b$. Let the parameters be $M=500,p_+=15,p_*=500$. I calculated, for all $m\in\{1,\dots,M\}$:
$\frac{1}{|\{p_++1,\dots,p_*\}|\cdot|\{-p_+,\dots,p_+\}|}\cdot\sum_{(x,y)\in\{p_++1,\dots,p_*\}\times\{-p_+,\dots,p_+\}}\frac{1}{|\{(m',x',y')\in\{1,\dots,M\}\times\{p_++1,\dots,p_*\}\times\{-p_+,\dots,p_+\}\ \mid\ T(m',x',y')=T(m,x,y)\}|}$. Essentially this is the probability of correctly guessing $m$, when you only know $T(m,x,y)$, for some $x,y$. The results of the computation:

Of course, this is not extremly secure (although it might be enough for some specific applications), but maybe there are ways to build up on that.
I found that such transformations are known as affine transormations, and there are many applications using this, or a similar concept. However, I was not able to find it being used in this context. Can anyone point me to some research on this, that I can look into?
